# Uint8Array stream buffer to video

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, socket.io-stream

I'm streaming video file from server to client. On the client side i receive Uint8Array and i don't know as use this array for streaming video.
what data format to convert it to and how to send it as a video tag so that the file can be played ?
The task is to stream an rtsp stream, but first I want to try streaming one video file

server

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('conn')
  let stream = ss.createStream();
  ss(socket).emit('stream', stream);
  let readStream = fs.createReadStream(mp4Path);
  readStream.pipe(stream);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnect')
  })
})
```

client

```
  const socket = io();

  ss(socket).on('stream', function(stream) {
    var binaryString = "";

    stream.on('data', function(data) {
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        binaryString += String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      }
    });

    stream.on('end', function(data) {
      binaryString = "";
    });
  });
```

Comment: The safest thing would be to convert the MP4 into a fragmented MP4 and then play the received bytes in a `<video>` tag by using Media Source Extensions.